# VirtualHost Same ServerName Different Directories

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I have a running production website assigned to a host (redmine application). I need to add a new application to the same host as a sub-directory.

This is the current virtualhost configuration for redmine application which runs at base folder of host.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName redmine.hostname.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/BitNami/redmine-2.5.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/public/"

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ balancer://redminecluster%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]

    ProxyPass / balancer://redminecluster
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://redminecluster

    <Proxy balancer://redminecluster>
       BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3001
       BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3002
    </Proxy>

</VirtualHost>
```

So this application already runs at **redmine.hostname.com**. I want to add my own application and i want it to run at **redmine.hostname.com/myapp/**.

Whatever i did, i couldn't achieve this. I must not change the path of redmine, i must add new app to same virtualhost. There are no open ports other than 80, so i must make it run at **redmine.hostname.com/myapp/**

Basically, the redmine application must reply all requests that do not start with **redmine.hostname.com/myapp/**. My App should reply all requests that start with **redmine.hostname.com/myapp**.

What settings should i use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your application /myapp is located is c:/myappdir, the easiest way to configure apache to do what you want is to use this configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName redmine.hostname.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/BitNami/redmine-2.5.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/public/"

    Alias /myapp "c:/myappdir"
    ProxyPass /myapp !

    ProxyPass / balancer://redminecluster/
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://redminecluster/

    <Proxy balancer://redminecluster>
       BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3001
       BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3002
    </Proxy>

</VirtualHost>
```

Using an exclamation point as target for ProxyPass will exclude /myapp from the proxy configuration as documented [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#ProxyPass). Additionally you don't need a special RewriteRule since you don't modify the requests to redmine, ProxyPass should be enough.

Comment: Thank you. This pointed me in the right direction to solve my issue. Especially "!" in ProxyPass.

Comment: One modification i made was to add trailing slashes at the end of ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse lines. So they became "balancer://redminecluster/". Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I also added <Directory "C:/myappdir/">...</Directory>.

Comment: I've fixed the trailing slash on ProxyPass. I don't think adding a <Directory> clause in the example is a good idea unless you give some idea in the question on your access requirements (I expect you simply added an "allow from all" but it's not really a universal requirement)

Comment: Inside directory clause, i am setting app specific folder permissions and so. So it is not a deal breaker but in case somebody needs it, they can use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It depends a little on whether your own app is hosted on the apache server itself, or it's proxied to another server/process.

If it's on the apache server itself, then just put 'myapp' into the document root. Then you need to remove your ProxyPass line and replace it with a locationmatch block

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName redmine.hostname.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/BitNami/redmine-2.5.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/public/"

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ balancer://redminecluster%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]

    <LocationMatch "^(?!/myapp)">
        ProxyPassMatch balancer://balancer://redminecluster
    </LocationMatch>

    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://redminecluster

    <Proxy balancer://redminecluster>
        BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3001
        BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3002
    </Proxy>

</VirtualHost>
```

So, the strategy is to forward everything which **doesn't** match /myapp to your existing redmine application. Everything matching /myapp will go to the document root. If your own app is proxied, then you need another locationmatch block which proxies /myapp to the correct location.

Comment: Thanks, my app is not proxied. It is hosted by apache. I can use alias and make it work in a seperate conf file. What should i write inside LocationMatch block in the example above?

Comment: You need to replace '/myapp' with your alias.

Comment: That's okay but what do i need to write in _LocationMatch_ tags? I mean instead of "ProxyPassMatch balancer://balancer://redminecluster" in your example.

Comment: I have tried above example without help. I can not make it work. Myapp does not use any proxy. Could you help out a little more? Thanks.

Comment: I need more information. What is the real name of the location for your app? The above should work if you replace /myapp with the directory/alias of your app. You don't need to change the contents of locationmatch. As I said in the answer, the strategy is to send everything which *doesn't* match /myapp to your existing proxy.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to solve my issue with "ProxyPass /myapp !"