# VirtualHost Same ServerName Different Directories (mirror codes)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, server-name

There is currently a problem as follows - [I have read this similar [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26719903/virtualhost-same-servername-different-directories), but I don't use proxy]

The official code uses the SVN version control under the root directory of the apache document root, which connects the official database.

I need to build a mirror (in other directory) which completely copy the SVN code, but connect the test database for testing.

But two directories site use same VirtualHost Servername
set as follows

```
<VirtualHost *: 80>
   DocumentRoot "E: / website-PHP / online"
   ServerName website
</VirtualHost>
```

The current situation is:
When connecting `http://website` and browsing sub-pages are normal, such as
`http://website/test` but when I connect to `http://website/mirror`
and browse the sub-pages, because of the path in the code was written Absolutly. `http://website/mirror/test` this page is replaced automatically
 by `http://website/test` and connection failed.

**※ I have tried using the rewrite engine**

```
RewriteCond% {SERVER_NAME} localhost [OR]
RewriteCond% {SERVER_NAME} website
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_URI}! Mirror
RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ Https: //% {SERVER_NAME} / mirror% {REQUEST_URI} [R = 301, L]
```

But the situation will become :
 `http://website` redirect to the test area `http://website/mirror/`

**※ try to use two sets of virtualhost:**

```
<VirtualHost *: 80>
  DocumentRoot "E: / website-PHP / online"
  ServerName website
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *: 8080>
  DocumentRoot "E: / website-PHP / online / mirror"
  ServerName website
</VirtualHost>
```

apache can start up,but can't connect to `http://website:8080/`
and didn't have any error log

Any Solution without editing source code?
Thanks!

**※ My apache edition is 2.2.25**

Comment: When apache won't start, something must be logged in error_log, take a look (my guess is that you need to add `Listen 8080` in httpd.conf)

Comment: I have add `Listen 8080` in httpd.conf file
but same situation.
By the way ,in the code didn't Specify the port...
So I have no idea.

Comment: apache can start up ,but have new question.

Comment: perhaps you need to open that port in Windows built-in firewall?

Comment: when i try to use `http://website:8080`,server  always redirect to `https://website`,https always port 443.

Comment: but i need rewrite rule to keep website in https.

Comment: You should probably open a new question, it is now difficult to trace what your current exact setup is

Comment: OK, i will still try it,thanks for your help. Now when I have to use mirror path, I will go to change my apache settings and restart it.